# Promise not working in chain of javascript /jquery functions

Tags: javascript

I have a series of async functions that i want to execute in a sequence, i tryed using promises but the exmple i followed tho it works, does not execute then in orther, and many times one resolves the content, before the other draws the container. i have tryed to understand the promises thing and it seems that the promises is being rejected, but i dont know what im doing wrong, or if i should use other method to "chaing" the functions. Thanks for the help!

```
var chain = new Promise(function(){
            statusUp();
        });
        chain.then(p_view(pid)).then(pu_list(pid)).then(pm_list(pid));
```

Comment: [Promise (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: You’re not resolving `chain` at all.

Comment: 1. You never `resolve` the promise, 2. you're not attaching callbacks to your `then`s, you're immediately executing `p_view(pid)` et al right there.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something similar to this

```
Promise.resolve(statusUp())
    .then(function(pid) {
       return p_view(pid)
    })
    .then(function(pid) {
      return pu_list(pid)
    })
    .then(function(pid) {
      return pm_list(pid)
    });
```

I made some (a lot of...) assumptions here regarding `statusUp`, `p_view`, `pu_list` and `pm_list` so this might need some tweaking.